# Django ImproperlyConfigured exception at app_name.url

Tags: python, django

This is a debug version of a running server, and the project's structure is in accordance with the online version, so this structure should be ok, yet when attempting to run the server I get an ImproperlyConfigured exception.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is
> not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patte
> rns and app_name instead.

I looked at online solutions but this exception can occur in many scenarios, and I couldn't figure out how to apply these solution into my code. I tried modifying the code as instructed in these solutions and kept getting this exception message.

Some relevant code:

**app_name\urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

polls.urls includes many url patterns.

[An image of the project's structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex5iD.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see apps.py in your polls folder.

from django.apps import AppConfig

class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'polls'

Comment: Put the name = 'polls' on another line with 4 spaces.

Comment: I still get the same exception. I also read in django's documentation that apps.py is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding

```
app_name = 'app_name'
```

in polls\urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

```
app_name = 'app_name'
```

Add this to `polls\url.py`